# In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, firebaseui

Trying to create a simple app with FireStore and Google Authentication. Having problem with the gradle:

> In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency
>   depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[15.0. 1]", but isn't
>   being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will
>   be unknown.
>
> Dependency failing: com.google.android.gms:play-services-flags:15.0.1
>   -> com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@[
>   15.0.1], but play-services-basement version was 16.0.1.
>
> The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or
>   have transitive dependencies that lead to the art ifact with the
>   issue.
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@17.1.5
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth@4.2.0
>
> For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with
>   ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep endency paths to
>   the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle
>   plugin, report issues at https://
>   github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding
>   "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your b uild.gradle
>   file.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 27
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "myapp.com"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 27
            versionCode 11
            versionName "1.1"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.5'

        implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.2.0'

    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin
```

Project gradle:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

    }
}
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There are many answers here for individual solutions that do not really get down to the problem. **Here is how to solve this in general**:

As the original log output suggests, it is useful to run the build in the terminal with the following command:

`./gradlew --info assembleDebug`

This will give you a list of all dependencies that are involved in the conflict. It looks similar to this (I removed the package name stuff to make it a bit more readable):

```
Dependency Resolution Help: Displaying all currently known paths to any version of the dependency: Artifact(groupId=com.google.firebase, artifactId=firebase-iid)

-- task/module dep -> firebase-analytics@17.2.0
---- firebase-analytics:17.2.0 library depends -> play-services-measurement-api@17.2.0
------ play-services-measurement-api:17.2.0 library depends -> firebase-iid@19.0.0

-- task/module dep -> firebase-core@17.2.0
---- firebase-core:17.2.0 library depends -> firebase-analytics@17.2.0
------ firebase-analytics:17.2.0 library depends -> play-services-measurement-api@17.2.0
-------- play-services-measurement-api:17.2.0 library depends -> firebase-iid@19.0.0

-- task/module dep -> play-services-measurement-api@17.2.0
---- play-services-measurement-api:17.2.0 library depends -> firebase-iid@19.0.0

-- task/module dep -> firebase-iid@19.0.0

-- task/module dep -> firebase-messaging@17.1.0
---- firebase-messaging:17.1.0 library depends -> firebase-iid@[16.2.0]

-- task/module dep -> com.pressenger:sdk@4.8.0
---- com.pressenger:sdk:4.8.0 library depends -> firebase-messaging@17.1.0
------ firebase-messaging:17.1.0 library depends -> firebase-iid@[16.2.0]
```

From this list you get to know 2 things:

1. Where is the conflicting depedency found
2. What versions of the conflicting dependency are set up

In my case the conflicting dependency is `firebase-iid`: It's either `@19.0.0` or `@16.2.0`

**To fix this you must define the top-level dependency of the wrong `firebase-iid` explicitly in your `build.gralde`.**

So in the upper log you can see that there are 2 examples of an out-dated version of firebase-iid@16.2.0. One comes from `-- task/module dep -> firebase-messaging@17.1.0` the other one from a third-party library (pressenger). We don't have influence on the third-party library, so nothing to do here.
But for the other dependency, we have to declare it explicitly with the correct version:

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'`

Now the build works again. Happy ending :)

Comment: Save my day. Thanks

Comment: But how did you jump from \@19.0.0 and \@16.2.0 to \@20.0.0

Comment: @baconcheese it's not about the different version of `filebase-iid`! Instead you have to explicitly set the dependency of all `task/module dep` which are using an outdated version of `firebase-iid`

Comment: This was tremendously helpful. Thank you so much for explaining your answer

Comment: @live-love can you mark this as the correct answer?

Comment: Well, it helped me a lot to know about this way to get gradle log directly, but I still had a hard time (and had to get lucky I think in a sense) to know what version to use for my top level dependency.  For me the fix was: "implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.0' " but I wasn't sure where to find what versions were even available for play-services-vision (20.1.2 was the latest I think?? but 20.1.0 worked).  I got this from https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: @Eradicatore it's less about a specific version to hit than about having the same version for all dependencies. You can find a list of common releases here: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases (use Ctrl+F to find the desired library)

Answer (score 26):

There's a [known bug](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1676) with Google Services 4.2.0 that may cause this. Downgrading your google-services version to 4.1.0 in your project's build.gradle may resolve the issue

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0' //decreased from 4.2.0
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'` even though I am getting error.

Comment: Downgraded to 4.1.0 and everything is just working fine now.

Comment: I have this problem while adding the stripe sdk. This method solves the problem. Never guess is the google-service problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

The problem was it was missing a dependency.
Adding com.google.firebase:firebase-auth solved the issue.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.5'

//    implementation'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
//    implementation'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'

    implementation'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0' => add this line
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.2.0'
}
```

Comment: how you come to know about this?

Comment: Use the latest version of 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0 to avoid run time error

Comment: How did you figure this out?

Answer (score 14):

There was a bug related to google-services that was eventually fixed in version `4.3.3`.

So you can either use 4.3.3 or the [latest version (check here)](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin)

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3' // or latest version
```

or downgrade to 4.1.0

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```

Answer (score 9):

i added the latest version of firebase messaging to build.gradle (Module: app) in my project and problem solved

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Easy and effective, saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 8):

Your `app/build.gradle` might have these lemon color blocked on dependencies part in Android Studio like on the picture below,

[image]

These (lemon color blocks) mean it's not latest version of dependency. just put mouse on each block, then IDE (Android Studio) tells the numbers that have to be changed.

Answer (score 5):

Updating all my Google Play Services libraries to the latest in ALL modules solved the issue for me. I don't see that you have any Google Play Services libraries, but I wanna leave this answer here to those that might find this useful.

Answer (score 5):

My project was working fine (No build issues). All of a sudden, I got this error

> "resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version.."

I figured out that it was because I was building offline.

If anyone gets the same error, **check if you are building offline**.

Comment: I was like you, project was working and suddenly I faced with this error, my problem was http proxy that I set in android studio, it was disconnected and I couldn't sync or build my project.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks, but unfortunately, this didn't entirely work for me. I also had to add the following to my build.grade (Module:app)

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-flags:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1'
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem was fixed after upgrading this lib in my project's build.gradle:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
```

and these ones in the app module's build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.5'
```

After this, use Android Studio's `Clean` menu

Answer (score 4):

I am using One Signal and caught this error once a time.

The reason was:

```
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

to put `apply plugin` for one signal before `'com.android.application'`.
Maybe this will be useful for some other `apply plugin` too.

Answer (score 3):

Add FCM to your App added Lower dependency Then I changed the dependency to the latest version this problem has solved.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
```

Answer (score 3):

None of the other answers worked for me. My use-case is with `React-Native 61+` trying to setup FCM and Analytics. What worked for me was using the latest `google-services` in `android/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2"
    classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3" // Need the latest here
}
```

And then adding the gradle dependencies to `android/app/build.gradle` required for the products I'm using (in my case Analytics and Cloud Messaging) from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?#available-libraries)

```
dependencies {
    ...
    // add the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just tried @live-love's [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54055643/3025856) myself and agree with the approach.

It might be more precise, however, to correct your dependencies according to [the latest Google Services library version](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries).

For my case, it happened when I just added/activated a Firebase service to the app.

You need to follow the latest version in project and Gradle app.

#### My `app/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    //Android Support Design Library
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    //RecyclerView
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    // Support multidex
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    // Firebase Core
    // implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    //Firebase Authentication
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'
    // Firestore Firestore
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
    // glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'

    // Circle ImageView
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

#### My project's `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Don't forget to sync the Gradle again.

Answer (score 1):

The working solution for me was to remove "firebase-auth" and add "firebase-core" dependency. But after a couple of project rebuilds I started experiencing another compilation issue so I had to add the "firebase-auth" dependency in addition to the "firebase-core" in order to make it work:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the line below in you Project's build.gradle (See image below)

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'`

[image]

Then update your Firebase related packages by going to :

**File > Project Structure > Dependencies > app**

Update Firebase modules to latest version (See the image below)

[image]

In my case I am using :

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.7'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
```

Don't forget to add :

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

See my Module's build.gradle file below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The ML Kit library had versioning problems in the latest release.

> Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version error (thrown by the google-services plugin)

Here is the link to the solution.
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#bom_v25-8-0

Answer (score 0):

This is new thing happen to me that If your network is not secure and you are getting prompt of Untrusted Certificate.

If you will **Accept or Reject**, It will give this error until your network will not be secure.

You can work offline by checking **Setting -> Gradle -> Offline Mode**

Answer (score 0):

If you used **song haesuk** answer, you need to do it for both build.gradle Project (classpath in dependencies), and in build.gradle app (implementations). Also do the same if you change builds for any libraries imported to the app.

I use suggestions provided by android studio and it changed implementations but did not change dependencies hence during build, there was a conflict between the two and it gave me same error.

Answer (score 0):

I replicated the issue when I accidentally added `com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision` twice with different versions.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by simply clearing the app-level dependencies block leaving just the default Android dependencies like so:

```
dependencies {
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
  implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This worked for me!

dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2"
    classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3" // Need the latest here
}

dependencies {
    ...
    // add the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case updating the firebase-bom and play services library to their latest version solved the issue:

In app level gradle :

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.3.2')
```

In project level gradle :

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
```