# android project in ... 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

I have a application that was working fine, but today it is giving errors while building the project.
I spend whole day and tried too many solutions from stack. Nothing is working.

I have following app -> build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.immuno"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "2.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false // here
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

    // Firebase libraries
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.0'

    // circular image
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'

    // RecyclerView
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    //FacebookSdk
    //implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.37.0'
    //implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.37.0'

    // volley library
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:17.0.0'
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8'

    // Glide library to load images smoothly
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'

    // To get date and time
    implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.10.1.1'

    // external libraries for mail
    implementation files('libs/activation.jar')
    implementation files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    implementation files('libs/mail.jar')

    // Add the Fabric Crashlytics plugin.
    //classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.2'
    // Add the Firebase Crashlytics dependency.
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'


    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
`
```

and build.gradle is

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and on building project I am getting this error

> ERROR: In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[20.0.2]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.
>
> Dependency failing: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0 -> com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@[20.0.2], but firebase-iid version was 19.0.0.
>
> ```
> The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
> ifact with the issue.
> -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@{strictly 19.0.0}
> -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-core@17.2.1
> -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-crash@16.2.1
> -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@{strictly 20.1.0}
> -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@20.1.0
> -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-crash@{strictly 16.2.1}
> -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics@17.2.1
> -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-core@{strictly 17.2.1}
> -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics@{strictly 17.2.1}
> -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api@{strictly 17.2.1}
> ```
>
> For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dependency paths to the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle plugin, report issues at https://github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your build.gradle file.

Comment: possible this topic help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54055141/in-project-app-a-resolved-google-play-services-library-dependency-depends-on-a

Comment: @javaddroid I tried that solution. I did not worked.

Comment: try to update all of your library to last stable version. and test again.

Comment: this happened to me today without changing any dependencies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is steps that I did and problem solved:

1. I changed `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0` to `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.1`
2. Sync gradle
3. And rollBack changes (change **20.0.1** to **20.1.0**)
4. If Sync and run app, you will see that problem solved!

I know this is not correct way but solved my problem. Any Correct should be replaced.

Comment: Thanks... I tried it before.. its strange but it works. Do you know the reason. Why it happens.

Comment: Maybe because of cache or something. really I don't know :/

Answer (score 1):

Try following two steps which can solve lots of this kind of issues -

1. Build -> Clean Project
2. File -> Invalid Caches/Restart in the menu you can just invalid caches or invalid and restart(which I prefer)

Cheers...

Answer (score 0):

For me the good old restart-the-computer-trick did it since after restarting Android Studio and clearing cache I had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just update the library version to

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.0'
```

Finally Sync the app, you will see that problem resolved!